# django-rest-auth: register an active user for my tests

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I'm trying to write some tests with django-rest-auth and the following code:

```
def create_user(username='john', email='johndoe@test.com', password='doe'):
    user = get_user_model().objects.create(
        username=username,
        email=email,
        is_active=False)
    if password:
        user.set_password(password)
    else:
        user.set_unusable_password()
    user.save()
    return user

def test_jwt_auth():
    username = 'user'
    email = 'user@foo.com'
    password = 'pass'
    create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
    resp = client.post(REST_LOGIN_URL, {'email': email, 'password': password})
    assertEqual(resp.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The `client.post` work fine as long as I don't change/create the user with `is_active=True`. When I do I get the following error:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ekami\Documents\workspace\NomadSpeed-Web\users\tests.py", line 64, in test_jwt_auth
    resp = self.client.post(REST_LOGIN_URL, {'email': email, 'password': password})
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 300, in post
    path, data=data, format=format, content_type=content_type, **extra)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 213, in post
    return self.generic('POST', path, data, content_type, **extra)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 238, in generic
    method, path, data, content_type, secure, **extra)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 422, in generic
    return self.request(**r)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 289, in request
    return super(APIClient, self).request(**kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\test.py", line 241, in request
    request = super(APIRequestFactory, self).request(**kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\django\test\client.py", line 503, in request
    raise exc_value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 45, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\rest_auth\views.py", line 49, in dispatch
    return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\rest_auth\views.py", line 103, in post
    self.serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 236, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 437, in run_validation
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\rest_auth\serializers.py", line 108, in validate
    email_address = user.emailaddress_set.get(email=user.email)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nomad\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 408, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
allauth.account.models.EmailAddress.DoesNotExist: EmailAddress matching query does not exist.
```

I have no idea how to bypass this error. I need my user to be active with a validated email to continue my test. Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`create_user` is looking to me as a [BaseUserManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model) so perhaps you should be change it to look like this

```
def create_user(self, username=None, email=None, password=None):
    if not username:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an Username')
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
    try:
        user = self.get(email=self.normalize_email(email))
    except self.model.DoesNotExist:
        user = self.model(username=username, email=self.normalize_email(email))
        password_validation.validate_password(password)
        user.set_password(password)
    return user
```

now you can pass user params and test.